# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. when sending messages with TPM Device client

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-iot-hub, tpm

We have a raspberry pi3 with a bpm180 sensor and we initializze the connection like this

```
 TpmDevice myDevice = new TpmDevice(0); // Use logical device 0 on the TPM
                string hubUri = myDevice.GetHostName();
                string deviceId = myDevice.GetDeviceId();
                string sasToken = myDevice.GetSASToken();

                deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create(
                    hubUri,
                    Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.AuthenticationMethodFactory.
                        CreateAuthenticationWithToken(deviceId, sasToken), Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.TransportType.Amqp);
```

And then we send messages like this:

```
public async void Bpm180Tick(object state)
        {
            string temperatureText;
            try
            {
                var sensorData = await _bmp180.GetSensorDataAsync(Bmp180AccuracyMode.UltraHighResolution);
                temperatureText = sensorData.Temperature.ToString("");
                temperatureText += "°C";
                var temperatureDataPoint = new
                {
                    deviceId = Global.GlobalTemperature,
                    valor = sensorData.Temperature,
                    fecha = DateTime.Now
                };
                //// actualizaciones de la interfaz de usuario... deben ser invocados en el subproceso de interfaz de usuario
                var messageString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(temperatureDataPoint);
                var message = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(messageString));
                //message.Properties["Ambiente"] = ambiente;
                //autoResetEvent.WaitOne();
                await deviceClient.SendEventAsync(message);
                //autoResetEvent.Set();
                var task = this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    Txt_Temperaura.Text = temperatureText;
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var a = ex.StackTrace;
                temperatureText = "Sensor Error: " + ex.Message;
            }


        }
```

However we are getting and objecct reference, but the error seems to be in the library(sdk), not in our code

the stack trace is thisÑ

```
  at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpTransportHandler.<SendAmqpMessageAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpTransportHandler.<SendEventAsync>d__19.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.ErrorDelegatingHandler.<>c__DisplayClass13_0.<<ExecuteWithErrorHandlingAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.ErrorDelegatingHandler.<ExecuteWithErrorHandlingAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.GateKeeperDelegatingHandler.<SendEventAsync>d__11.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at ActiveSense.Tempsense.Sensor.MainPage.<Bpm180Tick>d__23.MoveNext()
```

Comment: Which line caused the exception?

Comment: the line that sends the event async.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if it is possible that temperatureText no longer exists by the time the asynchronize code is running.  I would first try making it a static class variable and see what happens.

Comment: I am debugging and it does exist

Comment: The variable is captured into the closure, it will continue to be valid.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the SAS token expired but the AMQP library is not giving you a helpful error. To confirm this, use a connection string with a SharedAccessKey:

```
DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString("...;SharedAccessKey=xyz;...", TransportType.Amqp);
```

If that works, you need to look into renewing your SAS token (don't leave SharedAccessKey in product code!). If that gives you the same error, the problem is elsewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

It could be possible that SAS token expires.

On the other hand, since Azure-IoT-SDKs is open source, you can reference the sdk source code directly to check on the error.

1. Remove your project nuget reference "Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client"
2. Clone the azure-iot-sdks repository side-by-side with your project
3. Reference the Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.WinRT in your project.

You should be able to debug the AmqpTransportHandler.SendAmqpMessageAsync source code to see what the problem really is.

I myself got no luck reproducing your issue on RPi3 with Windows IoT Core 14393.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because there is a bug in the TPM library that I filed an issue and fixing pull request for.

Here is a link to the issue: https://github.com/ms-iot/security/issues/11

The SAS token expires immediately. The only reason it works for a while because IoT Hub allows some clock skew. I am still awaiting a new version of Microsoft.Devices.Tpm on NuGet.